# Mouse-follower in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, npm, frontend

I am using mouse-follower npm, so when I hover on a div an image should popup until I dont move the cursor outside of that div. In that page it is working properly.But I have used "react-router-dom" Link. So when I route to another page, the hovered image is still showing all over the new page, its not disappearing.Even that hover image in the circle is showing on the navbar and footer. It disappears when I reload, but I don't want that.
Here are my code below.

homepage:

```
<Link to={"/details"} state={{ title: title }} style={{
        textDecoration: "none", color: "black"
      }}>
        <Box 
          data-cursor-img={image}>
          <Box sx={{
            my: "3rem", display: 'flex', flexDirection: "column",
            alignItems: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            height: '10vh',
            textDecoration: "none"
          }}>

            
            <Box sx={{ fontSize: "3rem" }}><i class={icon}></i></Box>

            <Typography sx={{ m: "1rem" }}>{title}</Typography>
          </Box>
        </Box>
      </Link>
```

otherpage:

```
const Otherpage = () => {
    const location = useLocation();
    let title = location.state.title;
    
    
  return (
    <div data-cursor="-hidden">
      {title}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Otherpage
```